# Resources to help in making a web analytics tool

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic, google-analytics, web-analytics

I have a moderate experience with Ruby on Rails, PHP, SQL an NoSQL databases and CoffeeScript.

I want to build a web analytics tool for people in my country for their local websites, that will also have a main page of top site ranks.

In the beginning I am not asking out of myself to have something as powerful as Piwik or GA, but I want to make a good start. I know I will have to use JavaScript, that is good, I will also need a server-side processing part, but I don't know how to efficiently put these parts together.

I would love to hear about a book about such topic, but I don't think there is one. If possible, please recommend materials and subjects I need to master to make out my plan. Maybe some aids that can help me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not go through how Piwik use its tracker? It is open-source, so all sources are available. 
Might be a good place to start!
[Piwik github](https://github.com/piwik/piwik)